# "roll the tape"

Tags: meaning, idioms, synonyms

I need to translate this sentence : "I am going to roll the tape of what she is talking."

However, I don't get what does it indicate?

what is the meaning of "roll the tape"?
Does it mean to  ignore or not care about someone's talk?!

please help me understand what does it mean. I googled it and I don't seem to find its meaning.

Comment: "Roll the tape" is adapted from "roll the film" which means "start the movie".  Presumably "the tape" is cued up and ready to "roll" on the tape player, and "rolling" it consists of pressing the "PLAY" button.  ("Tape" in this case is magnetic audio or video tape, on reels.)

Comment: Note that the sentence "I am going to roll the tape of what she is talking" is not exactly idiomatic. In fact, I'm having a hard time making sense of it.

Comment: What @Marthaª  says is correct.  It should be something like "I am going to roll the tape of what she said", or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The tape* refers to audio recording tape, which was popular as recently as 10 years ago for recording people. *Roll the tape* refers to the playback machine that spins the tape, which looks like a wheel rolling. It basically means to playback something someone has said in the past.

Comment: It could also refer to video tape.